# Can I lose data from Cassandra cluster when updating Kairos?

Tags: cassandra, kairosdb

We have Kairos version 1.1.0-1.20151117201521 running on one server and 3 server cluster Cassandra and we want to update Kairos to a newer version.

We want to run a new Kairos version 1.2.2-1.20181109205636 on a new server (in case we need to revert back to the old one).

1. Can we try this without the possibility of loosing data from the Cassandra cluster?
2. Can we simply revert back if something goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally tested it.

But from the [google-groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/kairosdb-group/upgrade%7Csort:date/kairosdb-group/WNoWOdRJA00/e1V6i2PeAgAJ), it seems it was pretty smooth without any loss of data. I would always advise taking a backup of Cassandra, just in case.
Cassandra [snapshot](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupTakesSnapshot.html) is a constant time operation.

Answer (score 0):

Kairos 1.2 doesn't alter any existing data, it adds new tables to C*.  New data ingested via 1.2 will not be visible by 1.1 but 1.2 can see old data inserted by 1.1 (and previous)

The recommendation is to install a separate 1.2 Kairos instance and make sure it can see all your data.  Then change ingestion over to 1.2.